# Formating parts of a string in TCL/ Tk tablelist cell

Tags: tcl, string-formatting, tk-toolkit

I wonder if it is possible to format part of a text string when using the (example)

```
 .tbl   cellconfigure $row,$col -text "ThisBoldArial AndThisAsSubscript"
```

command?

I do know about eg the -font option, but this sets the font of the whole cell. Can I somehow format different parts of the string different?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it *easily*. Looking at [the documentation](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html), I can't see any way of indicating index ranges of cell text contents (which you'd need in order to apply a rendering variation to them). I guess you could work around it by embedding a text widget as the cell's renderer window with the `-window` cell option; the use of a text (or ctext) widget for this purpose is mentioned in passing in [documentation of the `-windowupdate` cell option](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html#cell_windowupdate) so it must be possible to fake it that way, but you'd need to figure out the details of how to make it happen right.

[This example](https://github.com/tcltk/tklib/blob/b8f56ba4cf816c5d726b2291d4aebdd182083ae1/examples/tablelist/embeddedWindows.tcl) shows how to do window embedding, albeit with a `frame` or `button` instead of a `text`. You'll need to do some work to get a text widget in there (basically make it borderless, read only and not scrollable at all).

> ```
> proc createButton {tbl row col w} {
>     set key [$tbl getkeys $row]
>     button $w -image openImg -highlightthickness 0 -takefocus 0 \
>         -command [list viewFile $tbl $key]
> }
> ```
>
> …
>
> ```
> $tbl cellconfigure $row,$column -window createButton
> ```

Naturally, you'll want to do more work to make the embedded text widget render as you want. That's potentially its own special set of complexity…

Comment: Thank you Donal for the idea! I've used the createButton proc before, so adapting it to a text widget should not be to difficult..